# Careers 2.0 Message list always empty in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

In Chrome, on both Linux and OS-X  (I have not tested Windows), if I go to `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/[myuserid]/messages` (eg: by clicking on "messages" in the top-left of Careers 2.0) the messages listing is always blank, despite there being a positive number next to the heading. The same is true if I go to "Sent Messages".

I also tried with all extensions disabled in Chrome, and I still encounter the problem.

I *cannot* reproduce the problem in Firefox or Safari.

Here's the "computed styles" from Chrome's Developer Tools:

```
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto;
border-bottom-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
display: block;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: 0px;
line-height: 18px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
text-align: left;
.container - left
vertical-align: baseline;
width: 675px;
zoom: 1;
```

The `height: 0px` bit looks suspicious to me, but I'm not sure how to go about debugging why that's happening.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this?

Comment: @NickLarsen Yes.

Comment: I tried comparing the page source between Firefox and Chrome, and they are the same modulo the XSRF key. I then tried using the element inspector in Chrome, and it appears that the message listing is there, it's just 0px tall. I don't have enough experience debugging CSS issues to know why that would be the case.

Comment: @NickLarsen have you tried to reproduce this on Linux? I no longer have this problem on OS-X, but it persists on Linux.